# After using groupby and unstack on Titanic dataset, can't graph a series of countplots

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

So my original dataframe `Cabin_hunt` looks something like this:

```
      Fare     Cabin    Pclass Ticket  
583  40.1250   A10       1     13049   
208  27.7208   A11       1     17613   
475  52.0000   A14       1     110465   
556  39.6000   A16       1     11755   
331  29.7000   A18       1     17580   
284  26.0000   A19       1     113056   
599  56.9292   A20       1     17485   
737  512.3292  B101      1     17755   
815   0.0000   B102      1    112058   
215  42.5000   B11       1    113038   
329  57.9792   B18       1    111361   
523  57.9792   B18       1    111361   
269  135.6333  C99       1    17760   
97   63.3583   D10       1    17759   
350  63.3583   D10       3    17759   
765  77.9583   D11       3    13502
```

I then proceeded to divide up the 'Cabin' according to the first letter of their 'Cabin' value. My eventual aim is to show the relation between Pclass and each Cabin group graphically. I created the groups via this code:

```
Cabin_group =Cabin_hunt.groupby([ Cabin_hunt.Pclass,Cabin_hunt.Cabin.str[0]]).size().unstack()
```

My output looks like this:

```
Cabin      A     B     C     D     E     F    G    T
Pclass                                              
1       22.0  65.0  94.0  40.0  34.0   NaN  NaN  1.0
2        NaN   NaN   NaN   6.0   4.0  13.0  NaN  NaN
3        NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   3.0   8.0  5.0  NaN
```

Cabin_group.columns and index outputs the following code:

> > > Cabin_group.columns

```
Index([u'A', u'B', u'C', u'D', u'E', u'F', u'G', u'T'], dtype='object',    name=u'Cabin')
```

> > > Cabin_group.index

```
 Int64Index([1, 2, 3], dtype='int64', name=u'Pclass')
```

Ideally, I want 8 graphs one one screen; one for each letter(A-T).
Within each graph  I would like to show three bars, with each bar representing the Pclass on the x-axis and the amount of observations on the y-axis.

I played around with `Countplot` and `PairGrid` but I couldn't get it work.

```
g = sns.PairGrid(Cabin_group)
g.map(sns.countplot)
plt.show()
```

I also tried something like this:

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(Cabin_group, col=Cabin_group.columns, size=4, aspect=.5)
g.map(sns.countplot,x=Cabin_group.index)
```

which in retrospect seems totally wrong.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as what I understand from your description of the graph you want to get, this is what I would do in an IPython Notebook:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

# Generate Data
data = np.array(
    [[ 22.,  65.,  94.,  40.,  34.,  np.nan,  np.nan,   1.],
    [ np.nan,  np.nan,  np.nan,   6.,   4.,  13.,  np.nan,  np.nan],
    [ np.nan,  np.nan,  np.nan,  np.nan,   3.,   8.,   5.,  np.nan]]
)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.columns.name = 'Cabin'
df.columns = 'A     B     C     D     E     F    G    T'.split()
df.index.name = 'Pclass'
df.index = [1, 2, 3]

# Plot Data
for no, col in enumerate(df):
    plt.subplot(2, 4, no+1)
    df[col].plot(kind='bar', title=col)
    plt.xlabel('Pclass')
    plt.ylabel('Amount of observations')
    plt.ylim([0, df.max().max()])
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

This is the outcome:

[image]

Comment: From a quick glance yeah this is along the lines of what I'm looking for!  The only thing is, for Pclass, I would like the values to be 1, 2, 3 instead of 0,1,2. You code looks more complicated than I expected (no wonder I couldn't figure it out) So I'm going to play around with it for a bit and see if I have any further questions. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: You are welcome! I set the index to [1, 2, 3] so that the Pclass values appear the way you want.

Comment: I'm confused as to how you were able to get the different  Pclasses onto the x-axis and the values on the y-axis. is this an automatic process when plotting a column on to a histogram? By plotting the column via histogram, the rows(index) get labeled on to the x-axis and the values get represented by the y-axis?

Comment: You are right. Just plot this Series object to see it for yourself: `pd.Series(data=[3, 7, 5], index=[2, 3, 4]).plot(kind='bar')` Though this is not a histogram plot, but just a plain bar plot.

Comment: [Here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.plot.html) it says that `use_index` is `True` by default, which means: "Use index as ticks for x axis"

Comment: Thank you so much. You have been very helpful.